# Initialize a Google Map with Knockout.js (ES6 Syntax)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

HTML: I don't know how to `data-bind` here, in the the line `<div id="map"></div>`
.

```
<div>            
<input data-bind="value: cityInput" type="text" class="search-input" id="city" placeholder="Enter a city"/>
<input data-bind="value: neighborhoodInput" type="text" class="search-input" id="neighborhood" placeholder="Enter a location in this city" value="Brooklyn"/>
<div data-bind="initMap()" id="map"></div>
</div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&v=weekly&key=APIKEY&callback=initMap"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
```

JavaScript: Everything seems okay, right?

```
   class ViewModel {
    constructor() {
        this.cityInput = ko.observable("New York");
        this.neighborhoodInput = ko.observable("Brooklyn");
        this.placeInput = ko.observable("Restaurants");
    }
    initMap() {
        let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({address: this.cityInput()}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                let cityLat = results[0].geometry.location.lat().valueOf();
                let cityLng = results[0].geometry.location.lng().valueOf();
                let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                    center: {lat: cityLat, lng: cityLng},
                    zoom: 10,
                    mapTypeControl: false
                });
                let cityOptions = {types: ["(cities)"]};
                let cityAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("city"), cityOptions);
                cityAutocomplete.bindTo("bounds", map);
                let searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById("place"));
                searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
            }
        });
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Somehow, the map didn't show as expected. It didn't show solely because of the lack of `bind-data` in the HTML or are there any mistakes in Javascript?

Comment: knockoutJs and google maps aren't connected, I can't tell from your sample but a common got ya for the map is that it's container must exist and must have a width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Given the way the Map API works, I don't think you can use Knockout's data-binding to initialize it(anyone correct me if I'm wrong).

Try this instead - simply call initMap function at the end of the viewModel, and remove the databinding from the HTML.

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

-

```
class ViewModel {
    constructor() {
        ...
    }
    initMap() {
        ...
    }
    initMap()
}
```